# What am I missing/what do I need to fix to make this code work?

Tags: android

I am slightly new to Android dev and wanted to test out Google's location services by retrieving the last known location and displaying it in a TextView, after clicking a button. Can anyone tell me how I should modify this code so that it will work? Thanks in advance:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
String latitude, longitude;
Button gpsButton;
TextView displayGPS;
AlertDialog.Builder dB;
AlertDialog errorDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gpsButton.findViewById(R.id.gps_button);
    displayGPS.findViewById(R.id.display_gps);

    //create new google api client
     googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this)
             .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (lastLocation != null) {
            latitude = String.valueOf((lastLocation.getLatitude()));
            longitude = String.valueOf((lastLocation.getLongitude()));
            try {
                gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Resources res = getResources();
                        String gps = String.format(res.getString(R.string.lat_and_long), latitude, longitude);
                        displayGPS.setText(gps);
                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                displayGPS.setText(R.string.location_unavailable);
            }
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult cr){
    dB = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Connection Failed")
            .setMessage("Connection has failed.").setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    errorDialog = dB.create();
    errorDialog.show();
}
}
```

Here is the strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Location Test</string>
    <string name="find_gps">Find Your Last Location</string>
    <string name="ok">OK</string>
    <string name="lat_and_long">Latitude: %1s &amp; Longitude: %2$s</string>
    <string name="location_unavailable">Location unavailable.</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: First I think %1s should be replaced by %1$s in string ressources. Otherwise, does it throw any error message ?

Comment: have a look this answer for step by step guidance http://stackoverflow.com/a/38397092/5955362

Comment: Thanks @JaydeepPatel , the code was helpful and assisted me in modifying my code so that it works

Comment: thanks @AlexandreMartin I missed that typo; now that I have looked at some example code from other people, I have been able to modify my code so that it works

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could check if **lastLocation** is null:

```
if(lastLocation == null) {
    Log.d("TEST", "TEST"); //Prints out to LogCat
}
```

If it´s so, you have to request the current location with

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

([developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html))
because then there is no last known location.
Otherwise if the application just crashes, **displayGPS.setText(gps);** isn´t called from the UI thread. Use **runOnUiThread** and set the text there.
**Edit:**
My bad, everything in **setOnClickListener** runs on the UI thread. Sorry about that.

Comment: Okay great, thanks, I modified my code and it works now