# Finding current location of the user in Android

Tags: android, android-location

I am new to Android and I am trying to develop an Android app which shows current location of the user. I am using Genymotion. Now I am using

```
mLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleClient);
```

to get the last location of the device. The thing is I wanted to get the current location but with this I get `mlocation` as not null that's fine. But in the map it shows last location of the device always not the current location.

**code snippet**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "inside onconnected Location services connected");
    Location mLocation=null;
    mLocationRequest= new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000)    ;   
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    }
               mLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleClient);
    if(mLocation==null)
    {
        Log.d("***Inside mlocation***", "***mlocation is null here");
    }

    if (mLocation != null) {
        onLocationChanged(mLocation);
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Im here!");

    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

and in `onstart()` I called `googleapi.connect()` and I used `setUpMapIfNeeded()` appropriately.

Please tell me whats the problem in this code. I am trying this for 3 days.

Comment: In your code no mention of gps on/off.
you should turn on gps during app forground.

Comment: hi jay, the gps in my emulator is turned on, but what i understood from your statement is i need to check for the availability of gps am i right..?? but then also it doesnt make any difference i think.

Comment: check my answer @Navi

Answer (score 1):

posting simple solution with code.

add permissions inside AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

if you app is marshmallow compatible then check run time permission.

add dependency inside gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

implements this two interface in you activity

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

and

create googleapiclient object like this in oncreate:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
```

and make this on start activity

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

here we go on result callback of location on this override method.

```
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + ":" + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

full code of activity is something like that:

```
public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = LocationActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);


    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
// connect googleapiclient
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
// disconnect googleapiclient
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
    // here we go you can see current lat long.
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + ":" + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}}
```

**p.s.** googleapiclient is not working in emulator without play services, so you have to test it on real devices.
please make sure gps is enable on that device.

if you want to use traditional method for get location then try this tutorial.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

**------UPDATE JUNE 15---------**

for latest apis 
check android google post: 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html

Comment: jay i have written same code as above. exactly same with some addition of marker thats it.. but not getting whats the problem.

Comment: you mean to say even after installing the google play services in an emulator, this code doesn't work..? as my geny motion have everything installed in it.. now what i have to do.. do i need to test it in my android mobile..?

Comment: jay you know what.. i am getting everything like latitude longitude and using geocoder i am even able to get address also.. but that is wrong because i am getting emulator previous location's latitude and longitude not my current location. i tried all the ways not getting whats the problem..

Comment: jay i cant share you apk file here in stackoverflow.. that feauture is not there.. then how do i give you that..??

Comment: @Navi lets chat in group http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117677/abcdxyz

Comment: hi jay did you check my app which i have sent you..??

Comment: i did check your code it is working fine @Navi Location is update regularly., please remove unnecessary comments.

Comment: ohh is it..!! its working fine..!! my god.. is the marker on the correct location of yours.? ya i will remove jay..

Comment: Jay when i run it in my genymotion its giving me loation somewhere in iceland not the loation where i am present..?? is this the same happening in your emulator..?? if not.. plz tell me what might be the problem in my genymotion..

Comment: yes marker is on right spot, and genymotion will show you location which you already set in this windows https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM5c-SrInOAhXFvo8KHYMhAxkQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F30709329%2Fgive-fake-location-to-genymotion-emulator&psig=AFQjCNELgonAEohevSwGU3w-DgG-A-rq_Q&ust=1469355020887439 @Navi

Comment: jay yes you are right.. but what i wanted is i want to get the location from mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleClient);

Comment: and this location should be my current location not the one which is there in genymotion.. and using that location i will get latitude and longitude of my current location.. i am facing problem in getting the my current location location..

Answer (score 0):

For Map Service, It requires Google Play Services. Make Sure Your Genymotion Has PlayService installed if not Get a help from [Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support) To Install Google Play Servies in Genymotion.
Happy Coding..!!!

Comment: hi raj, google play services are installed correctly.

Comment: Google Map Api With Android Official Documentation Here->https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Answer (score 0):

```
     LocationListener locationListener;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;  


       locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        locationListener = new LocationListener()
        {
            @Override


            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
  }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            ;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000, 0, locationListener);



        Log.e("location", longitude + " " + latitude);
```

Comment: Hi Nandish i added the same code and changed accordingly but still i am getting the same old location. and here in the above code i have a doubt, when onLocationChanged() is called the location object is null right..?? as we are not passing any value to it.. and please suggest me..