# Get current location latitude and longitude for API 23 and above in Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-maps-api-2

How to get current location latitude and longitude for API 23 and above in Android ?
Below functions gives `null`

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

and

```
mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
```

Comment: if it is null then ask for Location updates like,mLocationMagnager.requestUpdates(parameters), then next time it will not be null value

Comment: @Allu Thank you let me try it

Comment: here is full code documentation step by step http://stackoverflow.com/a/38397092/5955362
please add runtime permissions for location.

Comment: have you requested permission before getting location

Comment: @Chordin4tion I tried that too.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I gave all the permissions , but forgot to add functions to check whether GPS is enabled or not. From Marshmallow we need to enable the GPS to get current location info.