# Setting up location services on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to set up **Location services** in an app according to instructions of **developer.android.com**.
I have inserted the following code into the **onCreate** method

```
// Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
```

The class names **GoogleApiClient** and **LocationServices** appear in red and **"Cannot resolve Symbol"** appears on the tooltip.
I have tried

- Rebuilding Project
- Cleaning Project
- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- using an import from  **developer.android.com**

> import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

but to no avail. Will anyone please advise me? :)

Comment: try restart your android studio ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're missing something in your gradle script. Please post it

Comment: follow this guide http://stackoverflow.com/a/38397092/5955362 if you have still problem then please comment here.

Comment: @Jaydeep Patel, your guide is very clear, however, when I inserted 'implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener' I got an error _ Class MainActivity must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method  onConnected(Bundle) in ConnectionCallbacks_

Comment: It's OK I implemented the abstract method :) Thanks!

Comment: great ! always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have You Declared this?

```
     private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

and add this to your gradle file, and then sync.

then clean and build.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}
```

Have a look at below link,

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup